# Installing scikit: gcc-4.2 not found, using Clang instead

Tags: python, gcc, clang, llvm-gcc

When trying to install scikit on my Mac (OS X Lion) I stumbled upon this error:

> gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead.

I searched how to fix this and [it seems](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/283) that the environment variable CC is not correctly set. My question now is, how can I change this and to what do I have to change this? In my `/usr/lib/` I do see the g++, gcc, llvm-g++-4.2 and llvm-gcc-4.2 executables. Also when I check `env` I don't see the CC variable. Even when I try to export CC=gcc I don't see it with the `env` command.

Comment: If `export CC=gcc` doesn't show up in the output of `env`, you have a problem, or a non-sh shell like `tcsh`. `echo $SHELL` should tell you the shell. And make sure you didn't miss `CC` in the output of `env`, eg: `env | grep CC`.

Comment: when I do printenv CC , I do see gcc , the error states that It can't find gcc-4.2 ...

Comment: Btw, if you're installing through `python setup.py build/install`, you can prepend that line with `CC=/usr/bin/gcc python setup.py build` (and possibly other variables for e.g. the c++ compiler).

Comment: And is this the right compiler to use ? Because there is this llvm-gcc-4.2 one too it seems

Comment: Which scikit btw? If I know which one, I could be tempted to give the instllation procedure a try myself. Note that my Mac with Lion does have /usr/bin/gcc-4.2, so I don't know where yours went...

Comment: well I took the one from github, which was not a good idea. I tried it with pip, but there were problem concerning numpy ... I don't understand why I have these many problems when they are all newly installed

Comment: that's not what I meant. There are multiple scikits: scikits-learn, scikits-image, scikits-fitting etc., and they're all hosted on github. I would guess you installed scikits-learn, but perhaps you meant *all* of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scikits is *explicitly* looking for gcc-4.2, it sounds like it's hardcoded in the setup procedure (bad idea i.m.o.).

I would then just go for the symlink solution; a bit different than my comment or Ramneek's answer, but pretty much the same:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. If you are using `make` to compile the sources, use the following command:

   > ```
   > make CC=/path/to/gcc CXX=path/to/g++ 
   > make CC=/path/to/gcc CXX=path/to/g++ install 
   > etc.
   > ```
2. You could permanently change your default compilers by:

   > ```
   > cd /usr/bin
   > rm cc c++ gcc g++
   > ln -s gcc-4.2 cc
   > ln -s gcc-4.2 gcc
   > ln -s c++-4.2 c++
   > ln -s g++-4.2 g++
   > ```

You should also give `clang` a try, though - it's not bad at all, and in many cases is known to produce equivalent or better-optimized programs than `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` and such shouldn't be in `/usr/lib/`, but (also) in `/usr/bin/`. The ones in `/usr/lib/` are subdirectories, the ones in `/usr/bin/` are the executables.

It may very well be that you have the libraries in those subdirectories, but not the actual executables and header files.

Have you installed the command-line tools during your XCode installation?

Comment: I have the command-line tools installed and I see gcc and g++ in /usr/bin/ (but no gcc-4.2)

Comment: You can of course always symlink `gcc-4.2` to `gcc`, but you shouldn't have to. Have you checked your shell; you'll need to find out why you can set `CC` as an environment variable.